# Link to file generated by Server at runtime

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Our app has a process of creating PDF files on the server and placing them into the /assets/files/pdf folder of our angular application. We then out open up a new tab in our app to view this pdf file created by the server.

In v4 of angular we were able to open up a new tab with a URL like http://localhost:4200/assets/files/pdf/3ff6d9d5-f433-4706-b928-b7da9a72a3ed.pdf and be able to view the newly created pdf.

However, as of version 5 of angular specifically 5.2.2 if the file did not exist in the assets folder at the time the application was compiled it will not ever show the file it. It always results in a 404 not found.

What is the proper way to handle linking to files created at runtime, or is there an option that can be specified in the angular-cli.json or build commands that allows the app to link to files that did not exist at the time the application was compiled?

Answer (score 0):

You're giving very little info of how you're actually running things, but since otherwise this would make no sense, I'm assuming you're running `ng serve` and creating the PDFs in your angular-app/src/assets -directory?

If so, it's because Webpack Dev Server doesn't serve assets from your hard drive directly, instead it copies them to a "virtual disk" every time you compile.

So you could either

1. save any of your .ts files to make `ng serve` recompile
2. run `ng build --watch` instead,  set up a simple http server to serve your
   dist -directory, and let your other backend create PDFs in dist
   instead. Or better yet, can your PDF backend also serve static files? Why not let him serve your dist folder since you already have a server.

Way no. 1 doesn't sound right cause /src is for development files, not for server generated stuff, so definately go for 2.  =)